# how to display json data in dropdown using reactj

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, dropdown

i need to display data in dropdown i haven given json data with code.

```
        this.setState({
           data : [
                         {id:1,type:A},
                         {id:1,type:B},
                         {id:1,type:C},
                   ]
                })


            <select className="form-control"  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}  >
                    <option >Select data</option>
                        {
                        this.state.data.map((i, h) => 
                        (<option key={h} value={i.type}>{i.type}</option>))
                        }
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json isn't correct...put quotation for string type value-"A", "B", "C"

```
data: [{ id: 1, type: "A" }, { id: 1, type: "B" }, { id: 1, type: "C" }]
```

JSX

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [{ id: 1, type: "A" }, { id: 1, type: "B" }, { id: 1, type: "C" }]
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select className="form-control" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option>Select data</option>
          {this.state.data.map((i, h) => (
            <option key={h} value={i.type}>
              {i.type}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```