# Convert JSON data to a select dropdown in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have seen a similar question here ([how to display json data in dropdown using reactj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65112678/how-to-display-json-data-in-dropdown-using-reactj)), but it does not answer my query.

I have some JSON data coming in from an ajax request in my react app:

```
"quotes":{

        "USDAED":3.6732,
        "USDAFN":77.588904,
        "USDALL":103.298421,
        "USDAMD":528.084946,
        "USDANG":1.795181,
        "USDAOA":628.150147,
        "USDARS":92.5812
    }
```

Its a list of currencies and their conversion rates.

I need to render a select dropdown list out of it in a react component such that the json data is transformed into keys and values:

```
<select className="dropdown">
<option key="USDAED" value="3.6732">USDAED</option>
<option key="USDAFN" value="77.588904">USDAFN</option>
...
```

Is there an easy way to traverse the json data and create a select dropdown in JSX?

Comment: [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see only one difference between your situation and the SO example: in the example the list of items is an array, in your situation it's the fields of an object.

using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) you can get an array of fields, and use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on this array to display all the options

```
<select>
    {Object.keys(quotes).map(element => <option key={element} value={quotes[element]}>{element}</option>)}
</select>
```

https://codepen.io/sanjar/pen/YzNLRWE?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through your object keys

Updated my answer to show html

```js
var data = {
  "quotes": {

    "USDAED": 3.6732,
    "USDAFN": 77.588904,
    "USDALL": 103.298421,
    "USDAMD": 528.084946,
    "USDANG": 1.795181,
    "USDAOA": 628.150147,
    "USDARS": 92.5812
  }
};
var result=[];
for (let key in data.quotes) {
 var ele = document.getElementById('sel');
  result.push({key:key,value:data.quotes[key]})
   ele.innerHTML += '<option value="' + key + '">' + data.quotes[key] + '</option>';
}



console.log(result)
```

```html
<select className="dropdown" id="sel">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see. So this converts the data into an array of objects. How then do I convert this array to a select/option list in my render function?

Comment: Thank you. I’ve upvoted your answer, but someone else has provided a much cleaner solution, which I’ve accepted.